# How to get all rows that have any of numbers given

Tags: r

I want to get all row that the first column is any of the numbers from vector c.

```
> c
[1] 1 2

> ratio
  [,1] [,2]
a   1     2
b   2     5
c   2     4
d   3     8
e   4     3

I want the answer:
  [,1] [,2]
a   1     2
b   2     5
c   2     4
```

Is there any sample way? Please,thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%in%` to create a logical vector by comparing the first column of 'ratio' with the 'c' vector, and subset the rows of 'ratio' by using that as row index

```
ratio[ratio[,1] %in% c,]
```

Comment: I am so sorry there was a mistake in my description.Thank you very much for your answer.!